# textFieldShouldBeginEditing didn't response

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "HZAreaPickerView.h"

@interface CodeNumberViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, HZAreaPickerDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *areaText;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *cityText;


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *areaValue, *cityValue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) HZAreaPickerView *locatePicker;

-(void)cancelLocatePicker;
@end
```

-----------------below's .m file--------------

```
#pragma mark - TextField delegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField isEqual:self.areaText]) {
        [self cancelLocatePicker];
        self.locatePicker = [[HZAreaPickerView alloc] initWithStyle:HZAreaPickerWithStateAndCityAndDistrict delegate:self];
        [self.locatePicker showInView:self.view];
    } else {
        [self cancelLocatePicker];
        self.locatePicker = [[HZAreaPickerView alloc] initWithStyle:HZAreaPickerWithStateAndCity delegate:self];
        [self.locatePicker showInView:self.view];
    }
    return NO;
}
```

When I click the UITextField, I found the textFieldShouldBeginEditing even not being called. What's wrong? I already connected the UITextField to the .h file.

I truly hope u can help, if u need more details, I'll add, do not minus my reputation cause I don't have much. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you didn't set the delegate, in your viewDidLoad set:

```
self.areaText.delegate = self;

self.cityText.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect UITextField delegate  or mention in your code ??

Comment: of course, see in the 1st line. you mean this right? if not, what do u mean？

Comment: Well @null had given the solution that only i meant:) which you had not done in your code and also same thing you can do through binding as well. Connecting the textfield delegate to your Appdelegate class object in your xib.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add `UITexFieldDelegate` like you have already done, but you also need to connect the UITextField with the delegate when you initialize it. You can add it programmatically or just connecting it in the xib file(or storyboard).

Programmatically:

```
 areaText; = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frane];
 areaText.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:areaText];
```